# How to change number of QuickPanel rows?

Tags: android-12, quick-settings

I have Samsung Galaxy A52 with Android 12. When I swipe down at home screen QuickPanel shows up with one row of icons. If I swipe again entire QuickPanel shows up.

I would like to increase the number of rows visible after first swipe. I searched Settings but I didn't find anything relevant.

Is it possible to add more rows? If yes, how?

Comment: Old article, but does this not work? https://www.xda-developers.com/customize-size-quick-settings-button-layout-samsung-galaxy/

Comment: I only know how to increase the number of columns (which would also let you fit more on one screen). If that's an option, watch out for GravityBox – a module for the Xposed framework that can do that and more.

Comment: @Firelord, the overall description looks like it for QuickPanel fully open (after second swipe). However I cannot even connect with adb, I have unauthorized device so far.